# How to add library project to an existing android project in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, android-library

how can I add a custom library project (in my example the [CuXtomCam](https://github.com/krazykira/CuXtomCam) library) to an existing android project using Android Studio 1.1?

I've read about changing the build.gradle file. But where should I place the library ressources?

Thank you in advance for all answers and comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import library into Android Studio:

- select File > Import, and then select the directory containing the project to import.
- a wizard will open and guide you through the rest of the import process.

When the project import has finished, it will open up a file called "import-summary.txt" which lists all the steps taken during import and suggestions for next steps. For example, it may note files that were not migrated, it may note missing components in your SDK install, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are different Import possibilities at File > Import. With "Import Project" I was able to import the library as a new project in Android Studio but not as a part of my existing application. With "Import Module" I got the error "Gradle Project Sync Failed".

Comment: `File->Import` get a new project? are you sure? your current project is open and running, the import should be adding library to your current project, rather than a new project

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the project then New>Module. from the new window select Import existing project. Give the directory. I think this will help