# Using support library v7 as a module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I need to add the Material Design library to the project in Android Studio.
The common way to achieve this would be adding a dependency in Gradle:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0
```

But the problem is, that my project should run on an continuous integration server(Jenkins), which has no access to the internet or some external dependency servers.
(I know this is stupid, but I have no influence on this problem.)

So the only solution I have is to add the library as a static module into the project, which contains all the code and res files in it, which are necessary.

My question is: is it possible to add those library as a module in Android Studio? If yes, how?

Hope Someone can help me.

Comment: Check my answer to [How to add library project to an existing android project in AndroidStudio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011217/how-to-add-library-project-to-an-existing-android-project-in-androidstudio/30011353#30011353)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it as a module from the the sdk folder
..\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support